# Conditional Replacement with Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Been trying to figure out the regexp pattern for following case:

**Input:**

`XYZ_1234.jpg`

`XYZ_1234 (2).jpg`

**Expected output:**

`REPLACEMENT.jpg`

`REPLACEMENT_2.jpg`

Thank you in advance

Comment: What tool/language are you using?

Comment: http://regexr.com/3fj7c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible in one step; you have to do it in two steps:

1. Rename it: http://regexr.com/3fj87
2. Remove unnecessary underscore: http://regexr.com/3fj8a

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping that it is possible to set up some sort of conditional expression.